# Regex to block pattern except in certain situations

Tags: regex, block

I am working with the following regex:

```
[\s.,_-]*[wW][\s.,_-]*[wW][\s.,_-]*[wW]
```

It blocks all instances of www in a chat window for me ... there in lies the issue.

I want it to keep looking for spaces and special chars before the first w and still block, but I also want it to leave words like `awwwwwww` and `ewwwwwwww` alone completely.

I feel like I'm not far off but I have exhausted my regex know how.

Comment: Are you trying to block urls?

Comment: Please clarify the question, give some example inputs for what you would and wouldn't like to accept etc otherwise this question will probably be closed

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com` I just got around your block. You could use `\b` for this, but that's not your main issue - you're just doing it wrong.

Comment: we are trying to block urls . im seeing instances of beople typing www, w w w, ww w, w.w.w., etc... to type them. The regex above blocks all of that ... but it also blocks awwwwwww and ewwwwww which we dont want

Comment: Why not try to block valid urls only? When you introduce whitespaces into your regex things get hairy. w w w . g o o g l e . c o m  is not a valid url.

Comment: In that case, you can't possibly prevent people from communicating URLs. `http://stackoverflow.com`, `awww.stackoverflow.com without the a`, `xxx.stackoverflow.com with w as x`, `stackoverflow.com with 3 w's in front`, `stackoverflow.com`, `vv vv vv.stackoverflow.com`, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @Doorknob you can stop them from communicating valid URLs but people don't need valid urls to understand that the other party is trying to communicate a url.

Comment: i understand that it doesnt block everything its just a tiny piece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you could use

```
\b[wW](?:[\s.,_-]*[wW]){2}\b
```

`\b` is a word boundary, `(?:...)` is a non capturing parenthesis.

But indeed, without more context it's hard to tell if your URL filter won't break on strange output.